# How to position two ToolStripStatusLabel to different sides of StatusStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-6.0, statusstrip

I am using .NET 6.0  with VS2022 IDE. How to place 2 toolStripStatusLabel1 at two corners of status strip control. I am not able to make any grouping. So please share some suggestions if it is possible.

```
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(151, 20);
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "SUM Count Average";
// 
// toolStripStatusLabel2
// 
this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel2";
this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1000, 0, 0, 0);
this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1151, 20);
this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Elaped Time";
```

Comment: `.Spring = True` + `.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right` -- Remove the padding and let it AutoSize, it should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either or the following solutions to set different alignment for the items of [StatusStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

- Set `LayoutStyle` to `HorizontalStackWithOverflow`
- OR Use `Spring` property of a label to control the flow.
- OR use a ToolStrip instead.

**Option 1: Set LayoutStyle to HorizontalStackWithOverflow**

Setting alignment for the items of StatusStrip doesn't work when the [LayoutStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip.layoutstyle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is Table. That's because of the [custom logic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/StatusStrip.cs,b1c31659f2fde5ea) that it has to support [Spring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-use-the-spring-property-interactively-in-a-statusstrip?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property. To solve the issue:

Set the [LayoutStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip.layoutstyle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the StatusStrip to `HorizontalStackWithOverflow`, then the [Alignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.alignment?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the desired ToolStripStatusLabel to the `Right` in code (because the Alignment property of `ToolStripStatusLabel` is hidden in design-time).

*Note:* Keep in mind that by changing the layout style, setting `Sprint` has no more effect.

**Option 2: Use `Spring` property of a label to control the flow**

You can use 3 [ToolStripStatusLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) items; Then for the middle one, set the `Text` to empty and set the `Spring` to true to fill the space. Then the items before the items before this one will be aligned to the left and items after, will be aligned to the right.

**Option 3: Use a ToolStrip instead**

Instead of StatusStrip, use a ToolStrip and add 2 [ToolStripLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), and for the second one, set the Alignment to `Right`.

*Note: The main UX difference is missing the size grip.*